# How to convert a list to a dict?

Tags: python

I am using `subprocess` to print the output of `ls`.

```
output = subprocess.getoutput("ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@10.127.6.83 ls -l --time-style=long-iso /opt/databases | awk -F' ' '{print $6 $8}'")
lines = output.splitlines()
print(lines)
format = '%Y-%m-%d'
for line in lines:
   if line != '':
      date = datetime.strptime(line, format)
```

And when I print lines am getting a large list in the following format:

```
['', '2019-04-25friendship_graph_43458', '2019-07-18friendship_graph_45359', '2019-09-03friendship_graph_46553', '2019-10-02friendship_graph_46878']
```

I am trying to convert the above output to a dict with the dates in `'%Y-%m-%d'` format. So output would be something like:

```
{ '2019-04-25' : 'friendship_graph_43458',
  '2019-07-18': 'friendship_graph_45359',
  '2019-09-03': 'friendship_graph_46553' }
```

and so on, but not quite sure how to do so.

Comment: `..not quite sure how to do so.` - Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @wwii Converting the list to dict.

Comment: @TreeHuggerRick please don't add irrelevant tags to your question -- in this case, `subprocess` had nothing to do with your question, which is about converting a list to a dict. Even though the list comes from the output of a `subprocess` call, your question is unrelated.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Noted!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically if you don't want to use `re` if all dates are formatted the same then they will all be 10 characters long thus just slice the strings to make the dict in  a comprehension:

```
data = ['', '2019-04-25friendship_graph_43458', '2019-07-18friendship_graph_45359', '2019-09-03friendship_graph_46553', '2019-10-02friendship_graph_46878']

output = {s[:10]: s[10:] for s in data if len(s) > 10}
```

---

```
{'2019-04-25': 'friendship_graph_43458', '2019-07-18': 'friendship_graph_45359', '2019-09-03': 'friendship_graph_46553', '2019-10-02': 'friendship_graph_46878'}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. Short and sweet.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression for each item in the list. For example:

`(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(.*)`

Then, you can just iterate through each item in the list and use the regular expression to the get the string in its two parts.

```py
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(.*)")
>>> items = ['', '2019-04-25friendship_graph_43458', '2019-07-18friendship_graph_45359', '2019-09-03friendship_graph_46553', '2019-10-02friendship_graph_46878']
>>> items_dict = {}
>>> for i in items:
        match = regex.search(i)
        if match is None:
            continue
        items_dict[match.group(1)] = match.group(2)

    
>>> items_dict
{'2019-04-25': 'friendship_graph_43458', '2019-07-18': 'friendship_graph_45359', '2019-09-03': 'friendship_graph_46553', '2019-10-02': 'friendship_graph_46878'}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, it was a typo on my end.

Answer (score 3):

For lines that start with the date; use slices to separate the key from the value.

```
>>> s = '2019-04-25friendship_graph_43458'
>>> d = {}
>>> d[s[:10]] = s[10:]
>>> d
{'2019-04-25': 'friendship_graph_43458'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) and [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
import re
lst = ['', '2019-04-25friendship_graph_43458', '2019-07-18friendship_graph_45359', '2019-09-03friendship_graph_46553', '2019-10-02friendship_graph_46878']
dct = {k: v for s in lst for k, v in re.findall(r'(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)(.*)', s) }
print(dct)
# {'2019-04-25': 'friendship_graph_43458', '2019-07-18': 'friendship_graph_45359', '2019-09-03': 'friendship_graph_46553', '2019-10-02': 'friendship_graph_46878'}
```